# What is the meaning behind Pussy Galore's name?

Tags: character, book-adaptation, james-bond, goldfinger

While I was watching [James Bond 007 - Goldfinger](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058150/?ref_=nv_sr_1) on TV, I remember a lesson I had back in high school. We were learning about how movies are affected/released by what is going on in society. We looked at [Dr. Strange Love](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057012/?ref_=nv_sr_1) and James Bond 007 - Goldfinger. I'm quite sure we were supposed to note the notations to nuclear weaponry, however in Goldfinger everyone just laughed their asses off when Pussy Galore's name was brought up.

Now, I may be trying to keep both my physical and mental virginity until I get a girlfriend, but I know what everyone was going on about with Pussy Galore (and personally I don't find it funny, I saw the film several times before the class and never found it funny). I know that the James Bond films are based off books which were out long before the movies were released. I've been wondering, was Pussy Galore's name really a take on the slag term currently used in porn or was there another reason why Pussy Galore was named this way?

NOTE: While the answer probably lies in the book rather than the film's development, there's no SE site for books (at least not named easily enough) and this curiosity has came from watching the film, not to mention I do not know how different the movie is to the book so there is a chance that Pussy goes under a different name in the book.

Comment: There *was* a Literature.SE site, but unfortunately it closed after seeing low adoption during the beta. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/literature

Comment: What about miss Plenty O'Toole in Diamonds Are Forever? I thought that was a funny, suggestive name as well

Comment: There's a new [Literature.se]! You can ask your questions about the books there!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It seems the women in James Bond's love life often have provocative names:

- [Honey Rider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_Rider), *Dr. No* (1961):  1960s sexual position name for reverse cowgirl
- [Domino Vitali/Petachi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_Vitali), *Thunderball* (1965) and *Never Say Never Again* (1983):  Dominatrix?
- [Kissy Suzuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissy_Suzuki), *You Only Live Twice* (1967):  "kissing machine"?
- [Tiffany Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiffany_Case), *Diamonds Are Forever* (1971):  beautiful outside, desirable inside
- [Dr. Holly Goodhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holly_Goodhead), *Moonraker* (1979): certainly a euphemism for *holy fellatio*
- [Judy Havelock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_Havelock), *For Your Eyes Only* (1981):  bondage term or wrestling lock
- [Octopussy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octopussy_%28character%29), *Octopussy* (1983):  (what can I say?)
- [Xenia Onatopp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenia_Onatopp), *Goldeneye* (1995):  none too subtle
- [Wai Lin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wai_Lin), *Tommorrow Never Dies* (1997):  sounds like *Way In* or *Whaling*, both implying forceful sex

I'm having trouble deciphering [Vesper Lynd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vesper_Lynd) (from several *Casino Royale* movies).  Vesper means *evening*, but I don't see how that provocatively fits with *Lynd*.

As for what they all mean:  maybe Bond can't be relied upon to independently identify his next sexual conquest, so they are named as though they have signs on them.

Or maybe Ian Fleming was poking fun at English society's prudish and contradictory morals.

Comment: You missed Dr Goodhead from Moonraker.

Comment: @Tom77:  I added it.  How could I have forgotten her?  :-)

Comment: So what does "Pussy Galore" mean? :)

Comment: I remember reading that Vesper Lynd was a (innuendo-less, for once) wordplay on “West Berlin”.

Comment: There's Dr. Christmas Jones in The World is Not Enough, which on its own isn't sexual but I'm sure the name was just a setup for the last joke in the movie: `I've always wanted to have Christmas in Turkey`.

Comment: @MrLore:  Wasn't there also a quip like *Christmas only comes once a year*?

Comment: Wasn't there a Miss Goodnight? (*Man With The Golden Gun*, I think)

Comment: Christmas Jones -- The World is not enough
Bond: [in bed with Jones] I was wrong about you.
Dr. Christmas Jones: Yeah, how so?
Bond: I thought Christmas only comes once a year.
Bond: I've always wanted to have Christmas in turkey.

Comment: More recently they've been fantastically parodied in the Austin Powers films, with "Alotta Fagina", "Felicity Shagwell", etc.

Comment: *Casino Royale* (2005) had Ms Broadchester. (You'll have to trust me on this.)

Comment: @Hugh:  I have that on Bluray.  I'll have to review it.  :-)

Comment: Wai Lin = 'wailing' not 'whaling'.  I hope.

Comment: Um. What WTAF? You've projected so much onto these names that I think we're seeing inside your brain more than we are Ian Fleming's. "Kissing Machine"?? The Tiffany Case thing. Bizarre, bizarre, bizarre.

Answer (score 19):

**The meaning of the name "Pussy Galore" is essentially "abundant sex" (with "Pussy" meaning sex and "Galore" meaning abundant).**

The name "Pussy Galore" is intended to make viewers laugh. The humor is largely driven by how the name is such an obvious, crude reference to sex.

Remember the movie came out in 1964, when audiences were much less de-sensitized to sex and to shock-humor than they are today. Also note that the most recent Bond films seem to have done away with the obvious-sex-reference names for Bond Girls -- probably because that stuff just isn't funny to enough people anymore, and might even be considered offensive by many.

Answer (score 17):

There is also a [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pussy_Galore) on the character, which explains the meaning and origin:

> As with many of Ian Fleming's creations, the name is a double
>   entendre—in this case with respect to pussy, which is both another
>   word for a housecat and a slang term for vulva and vagina, while
>   galore means an abundant or plentiful supply of something.

Comment: Hardly a *double* entendre. Joey from Friends couldn't misunderstand it.

Answer (score 8):

That's really a question only Ian Fleming can answer, but he did use double entendres quite often when naming his female characters. In this case the double entendre is (hidden because it's not polite conversation):

> a housecat and vulva.

Comment: **In this case the double entendre is a housecat and vulva.**... I can't believe you actually typed that out, man.

Comment: just answering the question...

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional, there you go, now you have to want to read it...

Comment: *"hidden because it's not polite conversation"* - What is impolite in an anatomical term? But nevermind, to each his own. ;-)

Comment: @BenPlont *there you go, now you have to want to read it*... ha ha ha, very funny. I just thought it was hilarious having to actually explain the meaning of a specific double entendre!

Comment: @ChristianRau I did that for the sake of humor, in response to JohnSmithOptional. I made up a reason, because it's not really a spoiler.

Comment: @BenPlont Yeah, I see.

Comment: Down-vote because "Pussy Galore" is not a double entendre -- and I guarantee Ian Fleming did not have "housecat" in mind :)

Comment: @ShaneF. Pussy doesn't mean the same thing in 1960s british slang as it does in contemporary America. What we call a stand-up guy they call a pussy, what we call a pussy they call a fanny, what we call a fanny they call a bum. The name is a well documented double entendre.

Comment: I think Wikipedia is wrong about Pussy Galore being a double entendre. A double entendre has double meaning, like this from Tomorrow Never Dies: when Bond is disturbed by the telephone while in bed with a Danish girl, he explains to Moneypenny that he is busy "brushing up on a little Danish" which could mean either practicing language or having sex. So if Pussy Galore is a double entendre, what are its two meanings?

Comment: @ShaneF. a double entender is a figure of speech that is interpreted iin two ways. One way is as her name. Another way is as female genitalia. https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=pussy+galore+double+entendre

Answer (score 2):

It's an obvious sexual innuendo ("pussy" is probably the most-often used slang term for "vagina", and if you don't know what "galore" means then you need a dictionary), which was spoofed in the Austin Powers movies ([Alotta Fagina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alotta_Fagina)).

Comment: What are you using as your basis of fact ... ? I'm not asking you what is "obvious" but what you can prove.

Comment: We **know** that, the question is more WHY? What's the meaning?

Comment: Why does it have to have **meaning**?  Can't it just be a provocative name?

Comment: @JohnnyBones It just seems that the asker didn't get the provocative name at all. So explaining it would make this answer an actual answer (well, in fact like all the other previously existing answers already did to great lengths). After all this answer seems like a comment as the only actual information it adds is the *Austin Powers* reference.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because the answer is not new - there are several answers already stating the obvious sexual innuendo.

Comment: Yet it's more correct than some of the upvoted answers which came after the first answer, and I even added the Austin Powers reference to make it easier to understand the reference.

Comment: @JohnnyBones. Not everyone here speaks English as a first language, and not all second-language users are up to date on their slang.

Answer (score -2):

The word "Galore" comes from the Irish term "Go Leoir" meaning plenty.

Comment: Why does it always follow the noun it modifies?  Is that a Gaelic practice?

Comment: @Malvolio: yes it is. 'food galore' = food aplenty/ lots of food

Comment: I mean, in general, do Gaelic adjectives follow their nouns?

Comment: They do as a rule, but not necessarily in the case of 'go leoir' - but then I wonder if that is even an adjective (plenty of cake - is "plenty" an adjective here?)

Answer (score -5):

Miss Pussy Galore was suposed to be a Lesbian . With that in mind, She Is surely a Pussy Galore. Abundant Pleasure but yet unbroken. Until 007 came. She turned as an ally to 007,after being detained by Goldfinger.
Some eventful night on the detaining room must've open Pussy's perspective on having a good time with a male counterpart... Maybe mr.Fleming had 0069 in mind
(?)

Comment: Huh????????????

Comment: This is a reasonable answer but you need to rewrite it for clarity and brevity.